# Determining fate of Soviet soldier from Azerbaijan captured by Germans in 1941?

Tags: germany, world-war-2, imprisonment

I am searching for my great grandfather Ismailov Isa Iskander's grave.

He was born in 1904 in Khanlar (Helenendorf), Azerbaijan. That city was founded by Germans.

Isa learned German language from his friends in Khanlar. 
In 1941 he went to the war. My grandpa was a Soviet soldier. When he took part in World War II he was captured in December 1941. According to official Soviet archives he wais missing.

After the Collapse of the Soviet Union a man who was also in captivity told told me that he saw Isa in Graz, Austria in 1944. Isa was captured by Germans in Graz, Austria and has a berth among the other captives.

Can anyone suggest how I can find out what happened to him after he was captured, and/or confirm any of the details of his capture and captivity above?

Comment: Hi, Aytan, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please review the material in the help center, especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Your question needed editing to clarify what it is you were asking -- you were asking about more than one thing and we like to see one question per question.You can edit the question yourself by using the edit link underneath your message, or other community members can edit it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching my late father's story which is similar.

He was conscripted into the Soviet Army from Azerbaijan, captured by the Germans, then served in the German army as many of the Muslim troops did when the Germans offered the choice of fighting against Stalin. But - they actually sent them to the western front and not the eastern front against the Soviets.

After the war, the Germans turned these men from Azerbaijan and other Muslim countries who had fought for them back to the Soviets who executed them as deserters.

My father managed to get away and got to a UNRRA camp in the British sector not far from Graz, in Judenburg Austria.

I would be interested in talking with you.  Please feel free to contact me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Could you add some links to resources or other information that would help others with their own research?  You can use the edit link underneath your answer to add more information. Our site has a different purpose than forums or query lists where researchers contact each other and then take their research offline.  If you need more information about the site, please take the [tour] and view the material in the [help].